# Mitigating leakage of asymmetric encryption scheme leaking the length of plaintext

Tags: public-key, padding

Asymmetric encryption schemes do leak something about the encrypted plaintext: the length of the plaintext. How can this be mitigated?

**My solution:** Padding the plaintext with some string of the arbitrary length – add 1 and then a string of zeros

What are some other ways this information leak can be mitigated?

Comment: compression of plaintext?

Comment: Some information is always leaked. Take a ciphertext of X bytes, then the plaintext is not an uncompressible byte array of a larger size. Q.E.D. If you have generic RSA encryption then the ciphertext size doesn't show any info on the size of the plaintext other than that the plaintext is ciphertext - minimum padding overhead - or smaller. Unless side channels leak this info of course.

Comment: Does having the RSA message be a key to encrypt the real payload work for you?